# Alfresco Community Rest api, add user to group

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco rest api to create users as administrator. When i post data from my form it creates the user but does not assign this user to the group.

```
public function adduser($user, $pass, $userName, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $group){
    $data = array(
        "urlPath" => "/people"
    );

    $params = array(
    "userName"  => $userName,
    "password"  => $password,
    "firstName" => $firstName,
    "lastName" => $lastName,
    "email" => $email,
    "group" => $group
    );

    return $this->callAPI($user, $pass, 'POST', $data, $params);
}
```

Can you help me, what i am missing here?

Comment: This is completely based on my hunch and previous experience, but does that group exist? Are you sending the group name with the "GROUP_" prefix?

Comment: $_POST = [
    'AdduserModel' => [
        'userName' => 'test5',
        'password' => 'test5',
        'firstName' => 'test5',
        'lastName' => 'test5',
        'email' => 'test5@email.vom',
        'groups' => 'GROUP_Testgroup',
    ],
];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the groups property should be an array, not a simple string. For example, the following JSON can be POSTed successfully to /alfresco/s/api/people:

```
{
  'userName': 'test6',
  'password': 'test6',
  'firstName': 'test6',
  'lastName': 'test6',
  'email': 'test6@email.vom',
  'groups': ['GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS']
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff I get this fro post but still cant add the user  $_POST = [
    'AdduserModel' => [
        'userName' => 'test1',
        'password' => 'test1',
        'firstName' => 'test1',
        'lastName' => 'test1',
        'email' => 'test1@hotmail.com',
        'groups' => [
            'GROUP_Name',
        ],
    ],
];

Comment: Can you try posting JSON to the endpoint using a tool like curl or postman? If that works then you'll know your problem is about syntax.